# Disable a string in array to prevent duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this application where i have to insert the same `string` in a `textbox` as the one in the `array`. The `strings` come by in a label, for every answer it will go to a random word/string that is in the array.

My question is: Is there any way to `delete` or `disable` a word/string in the `array` so I don't get any duplicates?

```
string[] arrProvincies = File.ReadAllLines(@"provincies.txt");

int counter = 0;
string Array = "";

string Array = arrProvincies[counter].ToString();
lblProvincie.Text = Array;
counter = rnd.Next(0, 12);
```

Comment: Just call `var provinces=arrProvincies.Distinct()` to get distinct entries

Comment: `Prevent duplicates` is not the same as `random selection without repetition`. What do you actually want?

Comment: I don't want to have the same string more then once.

Comment: @Tuur you are looking for *shuffling*, generating a random order from the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Queue<string> arrProvincies = new Queue<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"provincies.txt"));
```

And use it with `lblProvincie.Text = arrProvincies.Dequeue();`

Thus you'll be sure to have no duplicate since your remove the entry when you use it.

---

If you need shuffling:

```
Queue<string> arrProvincies = new Queue<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"provincies.txt").OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Comment: The OP is trying to retrieve entries randomly. The lines should be shuffled before loading in the queue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, added info.

Comment: @Tuur replace your declaration of `arrProcincies` with mine

Comment: Only problem is, it will go by the same order everytime, it might be shuffled, but that stays the same everytime

Comment: I think you want `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of `new Guid()`, as that will give you random Guids and not just `Guid.Empty`

Comment: How would queuing and dequeueing prevent duplicates? It wouldn't, would it?

Comment: @cetinbasoz it ensure that the same string is not used twice since it's removed from the queue. Of course, this needs the source file to not contains duplicate content

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] arrProvincies = File.ReadAllLines(@"provincies.txt");

var randomProvincies = arrProvincies.Distinct().OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
```

randomProvincies would be the distinct values ordered randomly (I couldn't understand the part where it says you would insert the same string in a textbox).